# Could not install the 'emulator' command

Tags: android-sdk, android-emulator

I'm trying to install the android emulator command on my ubuntu 22.04 machine. This is what I've done to try to install everything:

```bsh
apt update
apt install -y android-sdk wget unzip

export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk

wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-8092744_latest.zip
unzip commandlinetools-linux-8092744_latest.zip
rm commandlinetools-linux-8092744_latest.zip

mkdir -p "$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest"
mv cmdline-tools/* "$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/"

export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

The problem is that after I've done all that, trying to run the `emulator` command gives me:

```
bash: emulator: command not found
```

I don't think that this is a problem of my `$PATH` being setup incorrectly, because the `emulator` command doesn't seem to be anywhere on my system since `find / -name 'emulator'` gives no results.

So, how can I install the `emulator` command correctly?

Thanks in advance, 
Robin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve my issue by simply running:

```bsh
sdkmanager "emulator"
```

This installs the `emulator` command. Make sure to also add `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator` to your `PATH` if it isn't already.